# Python error AuthenticationError: (Status 400) (Quandl Error QEAx01) We could not recognize your API key. Please check your API key and try again

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
# quandl for financial data
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'getyourownkey!'
# Retrieve TSLA data from Quandl
tesla = quandl.get('WIKI/TSLA')
```

**AuthenticationError**: (Status 400) (Quandl Error QEAx01) We could not recognize your API key. Please check your API key and try again.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: It seems you need your own key. So I'm guessing register for an api key on the quandl website?

Comment: After signup you will get an api key and then you need to confirm your email account to make it work. Replace 'getyourownkey!' with your 20 characters key.

Comment: Thanks. I registered with quandl and received my API key. It's working now.